# Android browser run javascript window.close()?

Tags: javascript, android, browser

Is it possible to close an Android browser window with window.close() or something related? I can't get anything to work on Android (on desktop browsers Chrome and Firefox I can window.close() without problems).

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, No.

I have a situation where I launch the zxing scanner app from my browser.  It returns in a new browser window.  I snag the data but then need to close that tab.  And have yet to find a solution to get that tab closed, either through a user clicking a button on the page or in the body load.  So it seems you can only put instructions on the page to have the user close the tab.